# How to iterate a hash map in response of ajax call where that map holds 3 lists

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, collections

here is my hash map and the ajax call

```
   Map<String, List<?>> map=new HashMap<>();

    List<?> minimumParameters=new ArrayList<>();

    map.put("min", minimumParameters);
    map.put("max", maximumParameters);
  //this is where i am calling that url and getting response
  //now how to iterate that response
   $.ajax({
        url:'./getMinMaxAvgDataByMtrNo/'+meterNum+'/'+frmDate+'/'+tDate,
        type:'GET',
        success:function(response){
            if(response.length == 0 || response.length == null ){
                bootbox.alert("No data for this meter number "+meterNum);
            }
            else{
                alert(response);
            }
        }
    });
```

now how to iterate that response to get those lists

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting the map in your response, you may iterate over that map in following way. Using jQuery,

```
$.ajax({
    url:'./getMinMaxAvgDataByMtrNo/'+meterNum+'/'+frmDate+'/'+tDate,
    type:'GET',
    success:function(response){
        if(response.length == 0 || response.length == null ){
            bootbox.alert("No data for this meter number "+meterNum);
        }
        else{
            alert(response);
            $.each(response , function( key, value ) {
               console.log( key + "=" + value ); // min=List<> , can iterate over list if you need to .
          });
        }
    }
});
```

Hope that is what you are looking for.